# Creating a dictionary and assigning a value of 0 per category

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary and assign a value of 0 to each value

Here's what I have so far:

```
c.execute("""SELECT category from wordtest order by category""")
catnum = c.fetchall()
catnum = [list(x) for x in catnum]
catnum = sum(catnum, [])
catnums = defaultdict(list)
for key in catnum:
        catnums[key].append(0)
```

But the output I get for this is `{"key": [0]}` and I do not want the value in a list.

Category in the database is just a list of words.

How would I make it so that the value of `catnums`, per key, is 0?

Comment: You created your defaultdict to have list structures . . . you want defaultdict(int).  The other answers are right in that you're making this much more complicated than needed.

Comment: @mgilson I fixed it before you responded - thanks for keeping me honest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I missing something?  Doesn't the following do what you want?:

```
catnums={}
for key in catnum:
    catnums[key]=0
```

Why do you need a defaultdict here?

Note that if you want a defaultdict which defaults to having values that default to 0, you can do:

```
zerodict=defaultdict(int)
```

since `int()` returns `0`.

Comment: Ah, beautiful and more simple too.

Comment: the `defaultdict` approach is weird because it would require to access all the keys just for side effects.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `fromkeys` dict method

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(range(5), 0)
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}
```

so your code will be:

```
catnums = dict.fromkeys(catnum, 0)
```

Comment: fromkeys -- nice.  It's amazing how many seldom used neat little methods `dict` objects have.  (+1)